# asp.net RegularExpressionValidator not working in mulitline textbox

Tags: asp.net, textbox, multiline

I am using RegularExpressionValidator to stop the user from using the apostrophe (symbol '). This is working fine in single line textbox. But it always shows error message when the user uses the enter key for new line. The ValidationExpression I am using is:ValidationExpression="^(?:(?!['].))*$"

And this is the code:
   
                                    ErrorMessage="You are not allowed to use apostorphene" 
                                    ControlToValidate="tbDrivingLicenseOther"
                                   ValidationExpression="^(?:(?!['].))*$">

Can not find the solution anywhere on the web. Can anyone help?

Comment: This is not an answer but why can't you strip out apostrophes at the server side?

Comment: I tried and doesn't work even with regular textbox ) your expression is more comlex than single apostrophe check.

Answer (score 0):

It isn't clear for me, what are you actually trying to prevent along with apostrophs with your current RegEx... but the following expression:

```
ValidationExpression="^[^']*$"
```

prevents input of apostrophes only in both TextBox and multi-line TextBox.

Comment: I don't want the user to be able to use ' in the text. When the user types ' the error message "You are not allowed to use apstrophene" will show. This works fine in sintle line textbox but does not work at all in multiline textbox because it will alway show the error message if you type more than one line.